# How do we say these in German?

Tags: english-to-german

how do we say these in german

_ in comparison (with/to something)

_ prefer somebody/something to somebody/something

_ prefer to do something

_ it depends on something

I would be appreciated if you make some examples

Comment: Note that this site isn't meant as a replacement for a translation service.

Comment: good to mention, but every site or translation service make individual translation. I don't know which one is the best translation for what I want. But here I can find a proper translation

Comment: This site offers assistance in learning German. You have to show some effort and point out *specific* problems you faced on your own attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im Vergleich zum letzten Winter ist dieser mild. - In comparison to last winter, this one is mild.

Ich ziehe Coke einem Pepsi vor - I prefer Coke to Pepsi.

Ich ziehe es vor zu dieser Sache zu schweigen. - I prefer to stay silent in this matter.

Meine Entscheidung hängt von ihrem Bestechungsgeld ab - My vote depends on your bribe.

Comment: Als es scheint, dass die Frage nicht den minimalen Anforderungen dieser Seite genügt, habe ich Zweifel, das eine Antwort angebracht ist. Dies wird auf Dauer nur weitere Fragen dieser Art generieren. Man könnte diese Beispiele stattdessen in einem Kommentar erwähnen und die Frage als _off topic_ kennzeichnen.

Comment: _"Meine Entscheidung hängt von ihrem Bestechungsgeld ab"_ Meine nicht :-)